# Standard sizes for Windows splash screens

Tags: windows, splash-screen

Is there a standard splash screen size or set of guidelines for the size of a splash screen?
This is for a music-playing application for XP and Vista.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Windows User Experience Guidelines in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511284.aspx only state that you shouldn't use splash screens, except for unusually long-loading applications. A splash screen size that doesn't get into the user's way too much (i. e. don't cover the whole screen, which should still hold true if the user has a lower screen resolution that the developer :)) should therefore be sufficient, if it is necessary at all.

Comment: But if the application takes, say, 15 seconds to load.  That is 15 secs where the user is not exactly sure what is going on.  Our client kicked up a massive fuss when we didn't have one.

Comment: Right, if the startup time is really long, then it's a necessary evil. But usually it's best to get rid of the splash screen and allow the user to interact with the program even if it's still loading content in the background.

Answer (score 4):

Purely based on experience: No.

Not even from MS applications, e.g. Office and Visual Studio have different sizes (and the VS one grows as more components are added).

Answer (score 4):

I found this Microsoft article in the UX guidelines for Windows apps: [**Guidelines for splash screens**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx).

It mentions this sizes:

```
Scale   Image size (pixels)

1x      620 x 300

1.4x    868 x 420

1.8x    1116 x 540
```

Answer (score 2):

I use my splash screen as my login window.  I just use 550X400 for my splash screen size as that is the size of standard wizards.